# Why is this jQuery draggable not cloning into the droppable area?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[My jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baragon23/nfdw62qa/5/)
When the user drags the menu item into the droppable area and drops it, you should see the element in the drop area with the original still intact up above but that is not happening. The drop is happening successfully as you can see the drop function firing off on successful drop. If I view the DOM as I drop the element, I can see the element being cloned and then instantly removed when I let go of the mouse. What do I need to do to achieve my desired drag and drop of an element?

```
<div class="node-pallet">
  <span>DIAL</span>
  <span>GOTO</span>
  <span>MENU</span>
  <span>HANGUP</span>
</div>

<div class="canvas"></div>

$('.node-pallet span').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move'
});

$('.canvas').droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    alert('Drop successful');
  }
});

body {
  background-color: #151824;
}

.canvas {
    background-color: #1f263d;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.node-pallet {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    width: 300px;
}

.node-pallet span {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have nothing that would append the helper to the droppable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one line.

Exmaple: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yj2osrte/

**JavaScript**

```
$('.node-pallet span').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move'
});

$('.canvas').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert('Drop successful');
    ui.helper.clone().appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

When it is Dropped, you then need to append a clone to the target.

Answer (score 0):

Use sortable with `connectWith` property.

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

> Sort items from one list into another and vice versa, by passing a
> selector into the connectWith option